# Python creates instance of None at the beginning

Tags: python, variable-assignment

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(None)
9392928
```

I see that None in python has been already instantiated at the beginning without me doing anything. Can someone help me to understand why I cannot do this even if None is just a 'name' for an object.

```
>>> None = 3
 File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
```

Comment: `None` is a builtin and part of the language.  It is not a normal name, it doesn't get "set" or "assigned".  There is a single instance of this type, the (more or less) keyword `None` accesses it, that's it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to ask. Are you trying to ask why you can't have instances of your own classes created at startup? Are you trying to ask why you can't assign to `None`? Are you trying to ask how `None` is created? Something else?

Comment: @user2357112 The question is whether someone can help understand.  The answer is yes.  The proof is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Python 2.7 specifically [forbids it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ast.c#L133-L149) (but does allow assignment to `True` and `False`). Python 3 considers it [a keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: It's a built-in — suggest you check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) _before_ asking such questions.

Answer (score -1):

It's one of the many built in constants. See here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html